# Unable to send and receive calls in Galaxy Grand 2 after kitkat update

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

Last week I updated my grand 2 to Kitkat 4.4.2 and now I am not able to send or receive any calls from my device when I dial any number it gives me the message "not registered on network", I have searched many solutions on internet but they are not helping me because after making 1 or 2 calls may device again stops making calls. If any one knows how to resolve this issue kindly help me, I am frustrated because of this issue as I am not able to do the basic tasks from my device.

Comment: A factory reset would solve the problem. Just remember to make a backup of important data.

Comment: I have already done the factory reset but it was of no use to me as it worked for some days and after that I am again not able to make or receive calls.

Answer (score 0):

when you say you "updated your phone" I'm not sure exactly what you're referring to. If you got an OTA (over-the-air) update from the settings menu in your phone (direct update from your mobile carrier), then you'll need to call the customer support for your carrier. They can usually reset your network settings remotely or walk you through troubleshooting the issue. If you updated it by rooting your phone and flashing a custom rom (you'll know if you did because it's a complex process that takes at least an hour) then you should try to flash a different rom. I've personally had problems with several roms not being able to place calls. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes i did got the OTA update, plus i tried inserting another sim in my device , but it is also not working in my device.

Comment: Since it was an OTA update, definitely call your service provider and they'll troubleshoot the issue. There's really not much else you can try on the device besides that. You could *try* to go into the about page in your settings and run all of the other updates if you need your device working right now. On the same page that you did the OTA update, try to 'Update PRL' and 'Update Profile', then reset your phone. If that doesn't resolve the issue, your service provider customer support is your best bet.